# Java regex : Remove (double) negative look ahead and look behind

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the following regex that matches a string to pattern:

`(?i)(?<![^\\s\\p{Punct}])` : Look behind

`(?![^\\s\\p{Punct}])` : Look ahead

Below is an example that demonstrates how I am using it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String patternStart = "(?i)(?<![^\\s\\p{Punct}])", patternEnd = "(?![^\\s\\p{Punct}])";
    String text = "this is some paragraph";
    System.out.println(Pattern.compile(patternStart + Pattern.quote("some paragraph") + patternEnd).matcher(text).find());
}
```

It returns `true` which is expected result. However, as the `regex` uses double negative (i.e. negative look ahead/behind and `^`), I thought removing both of the negatives should return the same result. So, I tried with the below:

```
String patternStart = "(?i)(?<=[\\s\\p{Punct}])", patternEnd = "(?=[\\s\\p{Punct}])";
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I even tried adding `^` and/or `$` in the end (of the square bracket) to match beginning/end of string, still, no luck.

Is it possible to convert these `regexes` into positive look-ups?

Comment: `(?=[\\s\\p{Punct}])` is not same as `(?![^\\s\\p{Punct}])`

Comment: Two negatives make a positive. However you'd need to be careful if using a negative character class to exclude a sub-class of a super-class. Example `[^\P{Punct},.]` Also, note that using two negatives has a hidden advantage of passing on anchors. So a whitespace boundary would be `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it is less efficient than what you have because in the positive lookarounds you need to use *alternation*:

```
String patternStart = "(?i)(?<=^|[\\s\\p{Punct}])", patternEnd = "(?=[\\s\\p{Punct}]|$)";
                               ^^                                                   ^^
```

The `(?<=^|[\\s\\p{Punct}])` lookbehind requires the presence of either start of string (`^`) or `|`  a whitespace or punctuation symbol (`[\\s\\p{Punct}]`). The positive lookahead `(?=[\\s\\p{Punct}]|$)` requires either a whitespace or punctuation, or  the end of string.

If you just add `^`  or `$` into the character classes like `[\\s\\p{Punct}^]` and `[\\s\\p{Punct}$]`, they will be parsed as literal caret and dollar symbols.

Comment: Ah okay, I tried using `[\\s\\p{Punct}^]` and `[\\s\\p{Punct}$]` inside the square brackets, hoping they would get `OR`ed with other pattern. It all makes sense now, thanks again :)